# SKU 1525, Missing Attributes standard_product_id,missing_keyset_reason.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Hi I am getting following, when try to added product submit feed

```
    SKU 1525, Missing Attributes standard_product_id,missing_keyset_reason. SKU 1525 does not
 match any ASIN. Creation of a new ASIN requires the following missing attributes: 
standard_product_id,missing_keyset_reason. Feed ID: 0. For details, see 
http://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/errorcode/200692370
```

here is my submit feed envelope

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
<SKU>1525</SKU>
<StandardProductID>
<Type>UPC</Type>
<Value>12345678</Value>
</StandardProductID>
<ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
<LaunchDate>2012-07-19T00:00:01</LaunchDate>
<ReleaseDate>2012-07-19T00:00:01</ReleaseDate>
<NumberOfItems>1</NumberOfItems>
<DescriptionData>
<Title>A really cool product2</Title>
<Brand>Racal-Dana Instruments, Ltd</Brand>
<Description>A really cool product with 2 batteries and widgets</Description>
<BulletPoint>Product Weight: 44 oz.</BulletPoint>
<PackageWeight unitOfMeasure="OZ">44</PackageWeight>
<MSRP currency="USD">219.00</MSRP>
<Manufacturer>Racal-Dana Instruments, Ltd</Manufacturer>
<MfrPartNumber>123456789</MfrPartNumber>
<SearchTerms>123456789</SearchTerms>
<SearchTerms>ACME</SearchTerms>
<ItemType>electronic-components</ItemType>
<IsGiftWrapAvailable>false</IsGiftWrapAvailable>
<IsGiftMessageAvailable>false</IsGiftMessageAvailable>
</DescriptionData>
<ProductData>
            <HomeImprovement>
                <ProductType>
                    <Hardware>
                        <Color>Black</Color>
                        <Material>Plastic</Material>
                    </Hardware>
                </ProductType>
            </HomeImprovement>
        </ProductData>
</Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

I have received the error `Missing Attributes standard_product_id,missing_keyset_reason` from Amazon quite a few times, and unfortunately it can be caused by a number of different circumstances.

From a quick glance at your feed XML I would recommend changing the `StandardProductID` `Value` to a valid UPC code (such as 847651325546). You can generate other valid UPC codes at http://www.upcdatabase.com/checkdigit.asp for testing out product uploads.

Comment: Thanks. it was indeed due to some other causes. For my case, I eventually found it was caused by non unique UPC codes that I was I adding to the feed. Once I sorted these error gone vanish. Pretty lame amazon error response and documentation!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the same error message when specifying a Department and ItemTypeKeyword that your account does not have permission to post items into. Anything in Jewelry was doing this as this was disabled on our MWS account.

Answer (score 0):

You are going too specific in category selection while downloading the template and you are probably not allowed to list your product under that sub-category.
Select the category you are allowed to post your products in and then download the template.